# Multiple characteristic frequencies determined by one capacitor

Tags: filter, passive-networks, resonance

I'm trying to figure out how to construct a filter with the following constraints. If it isn't possible, this would also be acceptable, albeit disappointing (and I would hope for some kind of proof). The important feature is that filter would only have one capacitor, but multiple characteristic frequencies, which both depend on the capacitor.

For instance, a normal bandpass filter has two frequencies \$f_L\$ and \$f_H\$ which can be easily identified, but they each depend on a different capacitor. Similarly, there is a filter to remove just one frequency (and narrow surroundings) from a signal, by attaching a resonant load across the circuit, but this has only one characteristic frequency -- the resonant frequency.

I would like to build something like that has *two* frequencies that it resonates at, or where the lower *and* upper boundaries of the bandpass filter are both derived from one common capacitor, but I can't find any simple way of doing this. I suspect that any answer will require a fairly nontrivial topology (eg. a lattice filter where all components are different). The circuit must also consist only of passive components.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This circuit has two resonances, both of which depend on the value of C1:

[image]

One resonance produces a peak in the transfer function and the other produces a null.